# How do I change text color to a specific textView in styles in xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout, colors

In android studios xml file styles I would like to change the color of a specific textView, but don't know how to reference it. All I can find is

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRed</item>
```

This changes the color to *all* textViews, but I need it to target a specific one. Haven't found anything by googling. Seems like a simple thing to do, just can't seem to find the solution... any ideas? It has to be done in xml and not java code.

Update:
To be a bit more clear: I have three textViews in styles and I want them all to be in different colors. If I use the code above, all of the textViews change. How can I set one color for each textView in styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in the xml for the TextView by setting the style.  It will look something like this:

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view_id_one"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/hello_one"
  style="@style/ColorOne"/>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view_id_two"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/hello_two"
  style="@style/ColorTwo"/>

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/text_view_id_three"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/hello_three"
  style="@style/ColorThree"/>
```

Then in your style file you can create three separate styles:

```
<style name="ColorOne" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_one</item>
</style>

<style name="ColorTwo" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_two</item>
</style>

<style name="ColorThree" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_three</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help since I want to set the theme according to the styles. With a button click I want to change styles, so all the textView color info needs to be in the styles xml file....

Comment: In your question you said, "I would like to change the color of a specific textView" which is what the above code does.  Sorry, I guess I don't fully understand what you are trying to accomplish?  If you want to change the color for a specific textview it's the way that I have it, if you want all the textview's to be changed according to a style, then it is the code you have in your original post.  You can specify a style that you would like the TextView to be based off from if that is what you want

Comment: Ok, I might have been a bit too vague. I'll update the original post :)

Comment: Ohhhhh I see! The update did make it more clear.  I've updated the answer I gave.  Is that more of what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense! Thanks for your help and sorry for not being clear enough in the initial post :)